# What is the name of this cast metal part inside my lockset?

Tags: doors, lock, hardware

I have a Baldwin front door *lockset* that doesn't completely retract the latch when using the thumb lever.  The *handleset* is similar to this: [model](http://www.baldwinhardware.com/Products/Details/door-hardware/entrance/180AEHXTBL-L03-SMT.aspx)

[image]

After dismantling the thumb latch assembly, I discovered that the source of the problem is a broken tread/collar in the mechanism that the thumb lever pin rests in. I'd like to replace this piece, but I can't seem to find it in any of the online catalogues ([build.com](http://www.build.com/baldwin-parts/c112830?source=gg_hw_baldwin%20replacement%20parts_31911064279_1t1&s_kwcid=TC|20913|baldwin%20replacement%20parts||S|e|31911064279&gclid=CK71lYnjm7gCFUmY4Aodf2wAVg), [handlesets.com](http://www.handlesets.com/baldwin-estate-parts/c5120), etc.). Any idea what it's called? The only reference to a part number on it is "05/02." I'd like to avoid replacing the entire lockset if possible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's probably a manufacturing date code (week 2 of 2005 or week 5 of 2002), not a part number.

Comment: If you are or can convince them you are the original purchaser it may be covered under their lifetime warranty.

Comment: I [emailed the company](http://www.baldwinhardware.com/Support/Contact-Support/Contact-Support-Form.aspx?supportType=prestige?supportType) and received a replacement part at no cost. For those interested, the part is officially called the "thumb lift assembly."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From surfing a bit, it seems Baldwin has a variety of handlesets that work with a limited number of their locksets.  If you can't buy just the plate, you might only need to buy the lockset.

It seems to be called a 'Landing Plate'

[image: http://d1fxhi9nz3487m.cloudfront.net/made-by-monkeys/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2009/01/lockk.jpg]

> http://www.electronicsweekly.com/made-by-monkeys/materialsmaterials-processing/view-image-youll-2009-01/
>
> We’ve had two Baldwin handle sets fail on our new front door in the
>   past six months, and I finally figured out why the manfacturer
>   included a second landing plate with the set.
>
> Basically they must have known it would fail prematurely.
>
> The thumb latch is a lever that sits on a set of little pins set on a
>   brass die casting, shown above, which allows it to toggle up and down.
>   Unfortunately, brass die castings are about making things fast, and
>   such parts typically have crappy structural performance and are prone
>   to stress cracking.
>
> What probably happened is that a tiny crack formed on one side of the
>   casting and propagated every time we squeezed up and down on the
>   handle.  One side failed (red arrow) and our door handle starting
>   twisting at an odd angle. Thankfully we replaced it with the second
>   landing plate before we were locked out of the house.
>
> After going through two sets, we bought a new set and discovered that
>   designers finally figured out they needed to reinforce the casting for
>   the load by reinforcing the area where the pin sets (right image).

Comment: A minor quibble about the quote: As someone who has repaired hundreds of locks and key cylinders, brass castings are actually the very best for a part like this. The one in the picture is electroplated with something yellow, but the casting itself is more likely zamac, which contains something like 3-5% copper. _Brass_ is usually >60% copper, and is much, much, more durable, both structurally and for wear.

Answer (score 1):

The part name isn't relevant at this point as Baldwin has re-engineered the part.  If you have an older one call their tech support and explain the problem and they will send you a conversion kit that will fix the problem.

Comment: How much is the conversion kit?

Answer (score 0):

It’s called the Thumprint Cartridge

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The original poster found out that it's called a "Thumb Lift Assembly"; where did you get the name "Thumbprint Cartridge"?